# Ansible with items in range

Tags: loops, ansible

I would like to achieve something like this with ansible

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "0"
    - "1"
```

But to be generated from a range(2) instead of having hardcoded the iterations. How would yo do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- debug:
    var: item
  with_sequence: 0-1
```

or

```
  with_sequence: start=0 end=1
```

or

```
  with_sequence: start=0 count=2
```

Pay attention that sequences are string values, not integers (you can cast with `item|int`)

Reference: [Looping over Integer Sequences](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences)

Comment: Amazing, I was fooling myself and there was a dedicated looping command.

Answer (score 5):

Because `with_sequence` is replaced by `loop` and the `range` function you can also use loop with range function like this example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: loop with range functions
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ 'number: %s' | format(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, 2, 1)|list }}"
```