# Loop from 0 to 100 with ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to loop from `s0` to `s60` and from `s100` to `s100` with this command:

```yaml
- name: "Network scan at port 22 {{ nom_base }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['exos_switch']
  wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ nom_base }}-{{ item }}"
        state: started
        timeout: 2   
  with_items:
    - s0
    - s1
    - s2
    - s3
    - s4
    - s5
    ....
    - s60
    - s100
    ...
    - s110
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible with items in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653092/ansible-with-items-in-range)

Comment: I can do that with "with_sequence" but i must jump some number

Comment: => Try this oneliner to get a list of your needed values`ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (range(0,61) | list) + (range(100,111) | list) }}"`. Use accordingly in your playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In respect to your question and comment a solution like

```yaml
- name: Show sequence
  debug:
    msg: "s{{ item }}"
  with_sequence:
    - "0-60"
    - "100-110"
  tags: seq
```

might work for you.

```yaml
- name: "Network scan at port 22 {{ nom_base }}"
  wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ nom_base }}-s{{ item }}"
        state: started
        timeout: 2   
  with_sequence:
    - "0-60"
    - "100-110"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['exos_switch']
```