# How can I do a for loop with Ansible?

Tags: bash

I try to create a for loop for this commmand like using Ansible inventory. I have an Ansible inventory and I want to create for loop for `CN=` also from inventory.

```ini
[kafka]
abc ansible_host=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
xyz ansible_host=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
tle ansible_host=10.xxx.xxx.xxx 
zsa ansible_host=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

```sh
for i in {1..4}; do
    keytool -genkey -keystore kafka.server0$i.keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass admin -keypass admin -dname "**CN=abc**" -storetype pkcs12
done
```

I try to create a for loop.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no further description where do you try to execute the key generation, use the result and what do you try to achieve overall. Maybe you can add more information and description.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In respect to your question and provided description an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: kafka
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Loop over
    debug:
      msg: '-keystore kafka.server0{{ ansible_loop.index }}.keystore.jks -dname "CN={{ item }}"'
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}" # over hosts within the group defined under hosts:
    loop_control:
      extended: true # to get the loop index
    delegate_to: localhost # which is usually the Control Node
    run_once: true
```

might work for you as it results into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Loop over] *******************************************
ok: [abc -> localhost] => (item=abc) =>
  msg: -keystore kafka.server01.keystore.jks -dname "CN=abc"
ok: [xyz -> localhost] => (item=xyz) =>
  msg: -keystore kafka.server02.keystore.jks -dname "CN=xyz"
ok: [tle -> localhost] => (item=tle) =>
  msg: -keystore kafka.server03.keystore.jks -dname "CN=tle"
ok: [zsa -> localhost] => (item=zsa) =>
  msg: -keystore kafka.server04.keystore.jks -dname "CN=zsa"
```

**Documentation**

- [Special Variables - `ansible_play_hosts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_play_hosts)
- [Playbook Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html)
- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)
- [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

**Further Q&A**

which are slightly similar ...

- [Loop from 0 to 100 with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483868/6771046)

Comment: i will step and try now

Comment: `kafka.server{{ '%02d' | format(ansible_loop.index) }}.keystore.jks`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, very good point, since there could be more than nine or ten (0-9, 1-9) hosts within the inventory and therefore play hosts list. So your example will add leading zeros if necessary automatically.

Comment: there are no way to make with for loop

Comment: @MuhammedOmar, is that a question? [Ansible isn't a programming language](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-coding-programming) therefore there are no such things exactly like DO WHILE or FOR LOOP. From the provided example you can see how to achieve the similar behavior.

Comment: @MuhammedOmar, since [Ansible uses Jinja2 templating to enable dynamic expressions and access to variables and facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) one could [Master loops with Jinja templates in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-jinja) and achieve the exact same result in such other way.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the *keystore* filename, the dictionary of keytool options, and *join* the options

```yaml
    keystore: "kafka.server{{ '%02d' % (idx + 1) }}.keystore.jks"

    kt_opt_dict:
      genkey: ''
      keystore: "{{ keystore }}"
      validity: 365
      storepass: testtest
      keypass: testtest
      dname: "CN={{ item }}"
      storetype: pkcs12

    kt_opt: "{{ kt_opt_dict|dict2items|
                json_query('[].[key, value]')|
                map('join', ' ')|map('trim')|
                join(' -') }}"
```

Iterate the command and generate the keys and create the files

```yaml
    - command:
        cmd: "keytool -{{ kt_opt }}"
        creates: "{{ keystore }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.kafka }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: idx
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      register: out
```

```bash
shell> ls -1 kafka.server0*
kafka.server01.keystore.jks
kafka.server02.keystore.jks
kafka.server03.keystore.jks
kafka.server04.keystore.jks
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    keystore: "kafka.server{{ '%02d' % (idx + 1) }}.keystore.jks"

    kt_opt_dict:
      genkeypair: ''
      keystore: "{{ keystore }}"
      validity: 365
      storepass: testtest
      keypass: testtest
      dname: "CN={{ item }}"
      storetype: pkcs12

    kt_opt: "{{ kt_opt_dict|dict2items|
                json_query('[].[key, value]')|
                map('join', ' ')|map('trim')|
                join(' -') }}"

  tasks:

    - command:
        cmd: "keytool -{{ kt_opt }}"
        creates: "{{ keystore }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.kafka }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: idx
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      register: out

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in out.results %}
          {{ i.item }} rc: {{ i.rc }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
ok: [abc -> localhost] => (item=abc)
ok: [abc -> localhost] => (item=xyz)
ok: [abc -> localhost] => (item=tle)
ok: [abc -> localhost] => (item=zsa)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [abc] => 
  msg: |-
    abc rc: 0
    xyz rc: 0
    tle rc: 0
    zsa rc: 0

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
abc: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```