# How to pass the specific array value to the variable in ansible

Tags: arrays, arraylist, ansible

I have a scenario where I need to print only 0th array and 1st array of 'N'of array in ansible.

Could someone help me to achieve this

**Sample code:**

**Array;**

```
ID = [1,2,3,4]
```

**Ansible Code:**

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Print the first 2 values in the array
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ID }}"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print the first 2 values in the array] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "2"
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print the first 2 values in the array] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": "3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) => {
    "msg": "4"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [Playbook Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)  and [`with_sequence`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop)

```yaml
- name: Show sequence
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_sequence:
    - "0-1"
```

**Thanks to**

- [Ansible `with_items` in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653092/)
- [Loop from 0 to 100 with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483868/6771046)

To get the value of an array you would use `ID[item]`. You may have a look into the following loop example and [how it works](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ID: [A, B, C, D]

  tasks:

- name: Show entry
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ item }} {{ ID[item | int] }}"
  with_sequence:
    - "0-1"
```

Comment: can you help me in replacing the variable in with_sequence? because that's where i get stuck

Comment: ```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ID: "['1','2','3','4']"
  tasks:
    - name: Print the first 2 values in the array
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ID[item] }}"
      with_sequence:
        - "1-2"
```
is this you're suggesting to do?

Comment: @Alfred, I've updated the answer accordingly with an working example.

Answer (score 2):

Use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ ID[0:2] }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item: 1
  item: 2
```

You can concatenate slices if you want to, e.g. to get the 1st, 2nd, and 4th item

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ ID[0:2] + ID[3:4] }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item: 1
  item: 2
  item: 4
```